# How to use polymorphism and generic class hierarchies with JAXB

Tags: java, json, generics, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm using Jersey and JAXB in order to output JSON for webservice calls and I have a generic type class hierarchy from domain model classes and I need to output the result of a specific class:

```
@XmlRootElement 
public class OfferDto extends BaseEntity<String> {
  private String name;
  private String description;

// ...
}
public class OfferListResponse extends BaseListResponseImpl<OfferDto> { 
}



public abstract class BaseListResponseImpl<T> implements BaseListResponse<T> {

    private List<T> data;
    public List<T> getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(List<T> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }       
}



public interface BaseListResponse<T> extends Serializable {
    public List<T> getData();
}
```

On my webservice I return:

```
OfferListResponse resp = offerService.getOfferList(params);
Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(resp).build();
```

but my JSON is being output as:

```
{"data":["sample.dto.OfferDto@2165c59c","com.sample.dto.OfferDto@fa69c419", ..."}]}
```

which seems JAXB is calling the toString method instead of properly outputting the object fields.

If I use concrete types directly in the class without any inheritance:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class OfferListResponse {
    private List<OfferDto> data;
// ... getters and setters
}
```

now it works fine.

I'm trying to understand what I need to do in order to use polymorphism and generic class hierarchies with JAXB?

Answer (score 0):

Use an `ObjectMapper`.

E.g. `new ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString()` which maps an object pretty to a `String`.

I've created an interface JSONMappable that allows me to write objects as Responses or Objects

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public interface JSONMappable {

  ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

  default Response asOKJsonResponse() {
    try {
      String json = OBJECT_MAPPER.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(this);
      return Response
        .ok(json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=UTF-8")
        .build();
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      return Response.serverError().build();
    }
  }

  default Object asJSON() {
    try {
      return OBJECT_MAPPER.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(this);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      return Response.serverError().build();
    }
  }
}
```

Then I implement this interface in all my resources that needs to be serialized to JSON.

So in your webservice you would use

```
return offerService.getOfferList(params).asJSONOKResponse;
```

The usage of an interface minimizes the clutter in the webservice